# Need Help on entity framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have 3 tables(Roles,Actions and RoleActionLinks). Roles table has few columns(RoleID,RoleName,Desc). Actions table has few colums(ActionID,ActionName,Desc). In RoleActionLink is created for store the association between Roles and Actions and this table has the columns such as RoleID,ActionID

When I created the data model(edmx). it shows only Role and Action as entity. i did not find RoleActionLink table. but even there is no direct relation between Roles and Actions table, both tables are automatically related using RoleActionLink table.

When i create the new Action, a action record should be populated in Action table(this is works fine). At the same time, i need to populate record in RoleActionLinks table. But i dont have the entity to populate.

Please tell me how to accomplish my needs.

Comment: You mean, here after, i will not get any answer. am i correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
newAction.Roles.Add(role1);
newAction.Roles.Add(role2);
```

Look at navigation properties in your model. There should be EntityCollection called Roles (name may differ).

Entity framework automatically handles n-n tables and creates collections on both sides.